# Run node debug on a remote master

Tags: ros, ide, clion, remote-roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have a question about IDEs and debugging.

I am currently working with a Baxter robot that has its own ROS core so whenever I need to launch a node I do that from a terminal where I set the master uri and other necessary variables (this is usually done automatically by a provided script). As my project becomes more complex it would be useful to use my IDE debugging utility but I could not find an option or a workaround to tell the IDE to run my code the same way.

Maybe you can give me a hint? I am currently using IntelliJ IDEs (pyCharm, IDEA, CLion) and I am mainly interested in the Python part.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234161/run-node-debug-on-a-remote-master/) by [alessiocpt](https://answers.ros.org/users/23182/alessiocpt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally found the problem. Apparently, you just need to launch pycharm from a baxterized terminal and it will work. Just sorucing ROS or modifying the desktop file as reported on the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) is obviously not enough.  Still, it would to have a way to set this inside the project or launch a "baxterized" PyCharm from the desktop launcher.

---

Originally posted by [alessiocpt](https://answers.ros.org/users/23182/alessiocpt/) with karma: 16 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0